# How can I insert data from a table into database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am wrote a script that dynamically generate data from database and output into a table, now I want the same data to be inserted into a database.
How to I achieve this please?

I want a way whereby and admin can query a database for users submitted task(the task the users submitted will be displayed in a tabular form), then write a report or review about it, then submit. On the process of submitting his report, I want the submitted report to be inserted into another table in the database, so that the users can still query the database to read the submitted report by the admin.

Actually, I have not yet tried anything, because I don't know what to try, I have search on Google for solution but can't find any.

Edit with code added 4/30 (for ease of reading):

```
<?php include('simple_html_dom.php');
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) { 
   $html = file_get_html('cpanel.php');
   foreach($html->find('a') as $td)
      echo $td. '<br>';
   $user = $_REQUEST['uname'];
   $title = $_REQUEST['utitle'];
   $desc = $_REQUEST['udesc'];
   $_date = $_REQUEST['udate'];
   $ucom = $_REQUEST['comment'];
   echo $ucom;
   $query = "INSERT INTO viewreport(Username, Title, Description, Report, Date) VALUES()";
?>
```

Comment: Do you really think an all-uppercase question title is appropriate?

Comment: Hi Josiah.  You might like to take a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask - or else you're unlikely to get any helpful replies.

Comment: Kindly update the information, Your saying you want to insert into a database what do you mean by that

Comment: You are trying to insert data (got from database) into database ? Again ? What are you trying please explain briefly. You may also check out this link on how to ask question in stackoverflow forum. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Here is what am trying to achieve.

Comment: I want a way whereby and admin can query a database for users submitted task(the task the users submitted will be displayed in a tabular form), then write a report or review about it, then submit. On the process of submitting his report, i want the submitted report to be inserted into another table in the database, so that the users can still query the database to read the submitted report by the admin.

Comment: where am having issues, is that the queried tasked submitted by the user are dynamic, so i don't have idea of how to get all data's in the table if they are generated dynamically.

Comment: A quick google about how to put form data into mysql example got me here:
http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-insert-data-into-mysql-db-using-form-in-php-database-enter-code-t868.html

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to allow admin comment on the first query and store those comments in separate database table ??

An outline of the flow you might use:

- Create database with table1 & table2, each having fields you want to separate data.
- Build a script that queries database, outputs to user and if admin user, contains form for comments.
- Add logic to this script that allows admin users to 'view' the comments also.
- Submit by posting user id & comments to another script that checks these and uses an insert query to enter comments and user id into second table.
- Depending on the result of submit and insert query, show the result to user.
- All the processing could be in the same script. Just divided by 'Step'.

For instance:

```
<?php
// get_database_info.php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$db_selected = mysql_select_db ( 'database_name' );
if ( first display  AND $db_selected ) {
   // check user for admin
   if ( admin ) {
      $query = 'SELECT field1, field2, ... FROM table1 WHERE ...';
   } else $query = 'SELECT comments, field1, field2, ... from table1 WHERE ...';
   $result = mysql_query ( $query );
   // Process & build the data to show in <body>
   $show = '...';
   // Add a form at the bottom for admin comments
   if ( admin ) {
      $show .= '<form method="post" action="get_database_info.php">';
      // Add input fields for user & comment
      $show .= '....';
   }
}
elseif ( submit comments AND $db_selected ) {
   // Build and enter insert query
   $insert_query = 'INSERT INTO table2 ( field1, ... ) VALUES ( 'abc', ... )';
   // Get result and build <body>
   $show = '...';
}
else
   $show = 'There was an error connecting to the database to process your request.';

?>
<html>
<body>
<?php echo $show; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can i insert a simple_html_dom.php to work<?php
 include('simple_html_dom.php');
 if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
 {
  $html = file_get_html('cpanel.php');
  foreach($html->find('a') as $td) 
     echo $td. '<br>';
  $user = $_REQUEST['uname'];
  $title = $_REQUEST['utitle'];
  $desc = $_REQUEST['udesc'];
  $_date = $_REQUEST['udate'];
  $ucom = $_REQUEST['comment'];
  echo $ucom;
  $query = "INSERT INTO viewreport(Username, Title, Description, Report, Date) VALUES()";
?> am still getting error:

Comment: Warning: include(simple_html_dom.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\csa-daa\hradmin\submit_report.php on line 2

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'simple_html_dom.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\wamp\www\csa-daa\hradmin\submit_report.php on line 2

Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_html() in C:\wamp\www\csa-daa\hradmin\submit_report.php on line 5

Comment: @Josiah These 3 warnings are saying 2 things: simple_html_dom.php is missing. Does it exist? And, second the function file_get_html is missing. It is probably in the included file. You can either expand the include statement to `include('/full_path_to_file/simple_html_dom.php');` or use the `include_path()` function.